# need to put integer number but it says lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, constants, scanf, assignment-operator

Edited: fixed some typos, also add more context

So I tried to put this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float ps, ls, ms, es;
    printf("Enter the project score: ");
    scanf("%d", &ps);
    printf("Enter the long exam score: ");
    scanf("%d", &ls);
    printf("Enter the midterm exam score: ");
    scanf("%d", &ms);
    90 = (ps * 0.15) + (ls * 0.2) + (ms * 0.25) * (es * 0.4);
    printf("Final exam score needed: %d", es);
    return 0;
}
```

As I want this equation 90=85(.15)+88(.2)+92(.25)+x(.4)

but it states that "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Comment: You are trying to assign a value into the constant `90`. I'm guessing maybe you're hoping that the compiler will solve a mathematical equation for you or something like that. This is not quite a the C language (and in fact, most languages that I'm aware of) works. I recommend that you learn the basics of the language first. Alternatively, if you're only interested in solving a mathematical equation, then there are other tools for that, such as Maple, or even the online website https://www.wolframalpha.com.

Comment: I had to do a double-take, but, are you trying to use C syntax to solve for an unknown variable in an algebraic expression?  C isn't a computer algebra system...

Comment: Rewrite the equation in a way that `es` is on the lhs of  `=`.

Comment: Thank you for giving insight. Is there a different method in C to get my desired result? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What IS your desired result???

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer Most general-purpose programming languages don't solve equations for you. If you want a result that's simple like this, your best bet is to do the algebra on paper and type in what you *actually* want the computer to do.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb its for my homework. sorry im gonna edit my post and post the full code for full understanding

Comment: what is `**90`?

Comment: @0___________ I apologize I keep on making mistake of my post. This is the final edit.

Comment: Please turn up your compiler warning level. `scanf("%d", &ls);` and other calls to `scanf` and `printf` should show some warning about parameter type mismatch for format specifier `%d`. For GCC you can use `-Wextra -Wall -pedantic`. You must use format specifier `%f` for `float` or use `double` instead of `float` and use `%lf` for `scanf`. For `printf` you can still use `%f` then.

Comment: Using some computer language does not mean that you can forget all the basic math you learned earlier about how to solve such equations. You must separate the variable you want to solve for.

Comment: what is `90 = `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others point out you need to use `%f` to read in `float`.

But here's an example that solves your equation:
Given the scores of the Project, Long Exam and Mid-term what score in the Final Exam is required for a weighted average of 90.

C is an 'imperative' procedural programming language.
You need to specify how to derive the `es` value.
It can't be expected to solve your equation.
The `=` means "assign to the variable on the left the value on the right".
It's not a statement of equality or even a logical test. It's an act of assigning a value into a variable.

I'm labouring the point because a 'breakthrough' understanding in programming is that equals "=" doesn't always mean what it does in Maths. In fact rarely does!

If you try 90, 90 and 90 below it will say 90 (which makes sense).
If you try 80, 85 and 90 you need a final score of 93.125.

This code does a back check to show the value calculated gives the right weighted score.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float ps, ls, ms, es;
    printf("Enter the project score: ");
    scanf("%f", &ps);
    printf("Enter the long exam score: ");
    scanf("%f", &ls);
    printf("Enter the midterm exam score: ");
    scanf("%f", &ms);
    
    printf("\nps=%f ls=%f ms=%f\n",ps,ls,ms);

    es=(90-(ps * 0.15) - (ls * 0.2) - (ms * 0.25) )/0.4;
    printf("Final exam score needed: %f\n", es);
    float check=ps*0.15+ls*0.2+ms*0.25+es*0.4;
    printf("Giving final score of %f\n",check);
    return 0;
}
```

Typical Output:

```
Enter the project score: Enter the long exam score: Enter the midterm exam score: 
ps=80.000000 ls=85.000000 ms=95.000000
Final exam score needed: 93.125000
Giving final score of 90.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
90=85(.15)+88(.2)+92(.25)+x(.4)
```

This should be

```
// solve equation for x
float x = (90 - (85*(.15)+88*(.2)+92*(.25))) / .4;
printf("Final exam score needed: %f\n", x);
```

Comment: Thank you but the final exam results to 0.

Comment: Because `es` is `float` and you are trying to print it with `%d`

Answer (score 0):

For starters you declared variables as having the type `float`

```
float ps, ls, ms, es;
```

So to enter values to the variables you have to use the conversion specifier `f` instead of `d` like

```
printf("Enter the project score: ");
scanf("%f", &ps);
```

This statement

```
90 = (ps * 0.15) + (ls * 0.2) + (ms * 0.25) * (es * 0.4);
```

does not make a sense. You may not change an integer constant. Also it is unclear why there is used the magic number `90`.

As in the next statement you are trying to output the value of the variable `es` again using the invalid conversion specifier `d` instead of `f` then it seems you mean

```
es = (ps * 0.15) + (ls * 0.2) + (ms * 0.25) * (es * 0.4);

printf("Final exam score needed: %f\n", es);
```

However pay into account that the variable `es` was not initialized. So the program will have undefined behavior.

Maybe you mean something like (though it is difficult to say what actually you mean)

```
es = (ps * 0.15) + (ls * 0.2) + (ms * 0.25);
es *= 0.4;
```